# Regular Expression with alphanumeric in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have to apply regular expression on my new web page that would accept alpha numeric with space.  This means that anybody cannot enter only numeric character.  If he has to enter numeric he has to enters string character also and can include space between names.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: means that anybody cannot enter only numeric character in that text box.if he has to enter numeric he has to enters string character also and can include space between them.means (hdfc bank12) is correct but (1233) only in that text box is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ language="C#" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     
                                    ErrorMessage="This expression does not validate." 
                                    ControlToValidate="txtName"     
                                    ValidationExpression="^a-zA-Z0-9\s" />
</form>
```

That example would check for Alpha Number and a Space.

For future reference have a look at:

http://regexlib.com

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx